# HTTP post and wininet

Tags: c++, winapi, http, networking, wininet

I implement sending POST request by using the wininet library. I tried to use the different flags both in the `HttpOpenRequest` and in the `PostInitWinInetHandle` functions. The generated request contains the `Cache-Control: no cache` header always.

Does HTTP protocol allows sending POST request without this header? If so how can I eliminate adding this header to a request?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the flag `INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE`.

Comment: I didn't use it, but the "Cache-Control: no cache" header appears.